# Textures with dimensions 8192x4096 are larger than the maximum supported size 4096x4096

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap, screen-resolution

In my application I have a Google map with a large bitmap inside which is used as a ground overlay. Here is the code

```
googleMap = map;
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

Bitmap myMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_park2);
GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions() // Загрузка картинки в карту
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0), 27000000f, 12735849f)
    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myMap));

googleMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

On the stage of testing I found a pretty interesting thing. On several devices with screen resolution 1920x1080 (LG G2, Nexus 5, OnePlus One and Sony Xperia Z3) it throws this exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 708
        Process: org.styleru.hseday2017_2, PID: 29768
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Textures with dimensions8192x4096 are larger than  the maximum supported size 4096x4096
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:109)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:35)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bk.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:60)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:76)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:626)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:270)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:257)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509438:11)
```

Despite the fact, that there were other devices with full hd screens on which my app worked fine (for example, Google Pixel and Meizu MX6).
In addition, I had such exception on HTC one m9+, which has screen resolution 2560x1440 despite the fact, that I also had other devices with 2560x1440 displays (for example, Moto Z). 
Resolution of the image inside the ground overlay is 1746x716.
I am just confused with this situation.
Why it happens and what should I do?

Comment: What directory is your `map_park2` in?

Comment: main\res\drawable